# Displaying images "not featured" with featured images in Django template language

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to display small thumbnail under featured images using django template language but for some reason main image displays fine but not small image. Idea is to display one featured image and rest as "not featured" images.

My single-page code to display "Featured Images" with "Not Featured" images is given below.

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}
 {% block content %}
 <h1>{{ product.title }}</h1>
 {% for img in images %}

 {% if img.featured  %}
 <h1>Featured</h1>
 <img class='img-responsive' src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ img.image }}"/>
 {% else %}
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
 <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
 <img class='img-responsive' src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ img.image }}"/>
 </a>
 </div>

 {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
 {% endblock %}
```

Please advise.

My models.py is....

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, default=29.99)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

   def __unicode__(self):
         return str(self.title)

   class Meta:
        unique_together = ('title', 'slug')

   def get_price(self):
        return self.price

   def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('single_product', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/images/')
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thumbnail = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

 def __unicode__(self):
     return self.product.title
```

Comment: What type of field is `featured`?

Comment: In my Views I've defined "single" function and field is...context = {"product": product, "images": images}. Rest is handled within template language.

Comment: Can you show how models in `models.py` look like?

Comment: Added models.py in question.

Comment: BTW, you can write `DateTimeField(auto_now=True)` instead of `DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)`.

Comment: Can you add line `print([img.featured for img in images])` before `return render...` and provide its output?

Comment: I added this under views for single function and its is showing the map from where it is rendering images. Do you need print for that?

Comment: It seems all images in template variable `images` are featured. The cause of this is a) all images of `product` are featured, there are no non featured images b) query in view to get `images` filter out all non featured images. Are `<a href="#" class="thumbnail">` tags in source code of rendered page?

Comment: @f43d65...post this as answer. You are right. Got it from your post and also took help from https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/ecommerce/blob/master/ecommerce/templates/products/single.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the images were set as featured and that was causing issue. Thanks for help @f43d65. Also consulted project on Github at: https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/ecommerce/blob/master/ecommerce/templates/products/single.html.

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace

```
{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ img.image }}
```

to

```
{{ img.image.url }}
```

Comment: I did it for only "not featured" first and then for "featured" and "not featured" both. Not resolved. Images for featured coming up fine but not for "not featured" category.